# kubernetes mount a directory readonly in all pod replicas

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, configmap

What is the best way to mount an external directory in a pod such that:

1. the pod access to the directory is readonly
2. whole directory tree is accessible in the pod
3. any change to the directory contents or creation of new files and directories in this directory is reflected to the pod instantly
4. all replicas of the pod see the same directory tree

Apparently any solution with ConfigMaps does not satisfy conditions 2 and 3.

Comment: What sort of data are you trying to share and why? Can you outsource your data storage requirement to a database - something like a redis or mongodb cluster rather than using a file system?

Comment: Just an example: save the configuration directory of apache2 web server in a central place; change the contents or possibly add a new configuration file there; then signal all pods to restart apache

Comment: Could you explain why ConfigMaps isn't applicable for you because you can store the directory with all includes directories and files in one ConfigMap volume.  May you have some problem with rights then just show it and we will help you to solve it. This is best practice to use ConfigMap to store configs.

Comment: @NickRack I created a test ConfigMap from a directory with --from-file but the subdirectories are missing from the ConfigMap. I am using minikube.

Answer (score 1):

Using configMap-s one can achieve all requirements (1) thru (4) except for part of (3) - changes to existing files content (by changing their configMap-s) will be reflected in the pods (almost) instantly but new files or directories won't.

The following script - see [here](https://github.com/apimastery/APISimulator/blob/master/kubernetes-deployment/apisim-kubernetes-deploy.sh) - implements the approach.

Notice that:

- (1) is now the default starting with 1.9.6 - see [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/62099) for a discussion.
- Key for (2) is the use of [projected volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#projected).
- (4) is out-of-the-box feature as documented [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#mounted-configmaps-are-updated-automatically), except for when using subPath.
- Using a single configMap for all files may cause "...ERROR: The ConfigMap "" is invalid: []: Too long: must have at most 1048576 characters".
- Using a configMap per file also has a size limitation of ~1MB for the file content (it is an etcd limitation).